# definition of a traveling wave (solution)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definition

today I've got a problem with understanding what is meant by the term "traveling wave solution" of a PDE in a more general sense.

To be more precise, I've got a following Poisson equation

\begin{align}\Delta u &= \delta (r,\theta,z-ct) \ &in \ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3\\
u&=0 \  &on \ \partial\Omega\end{align}

where $\delta$ is the delta-distribution, $\Omega$ unbounded domain and the PDE is given in cylindrical coordniates.

Now it is said that there exists a travelling wave solution $u$ satisfying the PDE. But what does that mean? I know the condition that there exists a function $w$ und $c$ with $u(x,t)=w(x-ct)$, but $x-ct$ makes no sense with $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and in addition I can't find literature dealing with a definition of traveling waves in higher dimensions.

Does someone know how to read that or knows relevant literature?

Comment: It does if "x" is a 3 dimensional position vector and "c" is a 3 dimensional velocity vector.  Writing x as $< x , y, z>$ and v as $<v_x,. v_y, v_z>$ the equation becomes $u(x,y)= w(<x, y, z>- <v_x, v_y, v_z>t) =w(<x- v_ct, y- v_yt, z- v_zt>)$.

Comment: Thank you, of course, this is right. But is it your interpretation how you would read it or did you saw something like that? The problem concerning that question ist the visual explanation the 1D-traveling wave has got. But is it justifiable to lift it up to 3D? I ask again because I found literature dealing a slightly different problem, but there was a stationary wave defined as a function $u(x,t)=w(x_1-ct,x')$ where $x'=(x_2,...x_n)$. So the other dimensionsare only ignored and I'm not sure if I can transfer it to my needs. I thought somone really can define it?